# Does Sitecore express migration tool support to upgrade from sitecore 7.2 to sitecore 9 update 2

Tags: upgrade, express-migration-tool

I could see that sitecore express migration tool supports to migrate from previous old versions to sitecore 9 initial version. If i have to upgrade to sitecore 9 update 2, what steps need to follow?

1. Do i have to upgrade to sitecore 9 initial version then later upgrade from sitecore 9 (initial version) to sitecore 9 update 2.
2. During migration what are the main areas to be focussed when upgrading from 7.2 to sitecore 9.

If anyone has done these kind of migrations, your inputs will be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sitecore Migration Tool supports migration just to initial release of 9. 
   You can find the compatibility table of the module here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/400952

   To upgrade from 9.0 to 9.0.2 you need to follow [Upgrade guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/A24AE0FB3EC947ACB8F6FCCFBA0CD8C3.ashx) from **9.0.2** release.
2. For the second point is difficult to give your the right answer. 
    You need to verify all modules and custom code to be compatible with Sitecore 9 after upgrade. 
    On 7.2 xDB doesn't exist, I guess you don't want to upgrade old DMS data to xDB. 
    If you are using Dynamics Placeholder on 7.2, you have to change your renderings (long story).

Comment: I don't think you *have* to change your renderings if you use an old dynamic placeholders library, as long as that library can run on .net462 target

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to change it, because the ids and the order of your placeholder settings is different in 9. Or you disable dynamics placeholders pipelines from 9 and you use the old ones. But I don't recommend to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would recommend you to go through the traditional approach of migration.
As per sitecore , they suggest that 
if you are upgrading from old version to new then you have to start from the next version of  the current Sitecore  version you are using and then you have to progress till the new version.

For ex. If you are using sitecore 7.2 then first you need to upgrade to 7.5

After that  from 7.5 to 8.0  and so on till 9.0

Comment: why?  The Sitecore Express Migration Tool helps to migrate older instances to the latest version of Sitecore Experience Platform without the need to gradually upgrade from version to version. The way you suggest provide any benefits? Please clarify.

Comment: Arjunan , I have done lots of Sitecore migration project and found that express Migration tool is helpful only when the Sitecore instance is not much complicated and customized . + points for quick migration, but there are certain disadvantages of migration tool as compared to step by step upgrade like as listed below  1. express tool will not migrate analytics data 2.  if you have a lot of customization in sitecore custom pipelines, overrided pipelines and other customizations as well then you may lose those changes